# How to get "configure" icons next to each block back?

Tags: blocks

My configure icons have disapeared. How do I get them back?

Comment: Are you saying that the gear icon that appears to the right of a block is missing, or are you talking of a different icon? May you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Maybe you can refresh your cache? Or a website reset? Have you look at it through a different browser? A picture of your issue would help....

Comment: I've cleared the cache. But how do I reset the website? It looks the same in IE8 and Firefox. Basically, there are no "configure" edit icons when I hover over the block area, anywhere. It looks the same as if I am logged out, except of course I am still able to configure all the blocks by using the navigation menu across the top... But would be convenient to have the configure buttons next to each block instead... I am using the zen theme...

Comment: Yes, it is the gear icons that are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the gear icon that appears when you hover the mouse over a block, that is output from the [Contextual links](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/contextual) module that comes with Drupal core.

[image: screenshot]

The same module adds contextual links to other parts of a page, such as a node.

[image: screenshot]

It also handle the gear icon that you see in the page to edit a view.

[image: screenshot]